# Git, merge two remote branches

Tags: git, git-merge

I created second branch -> git checkout -b branch2
After it, created any file, add, commit and push to branch2.

Now I checkout to master branch. How can I added new_file from branch2 to master branch? Any merge option -> your branch is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much information about your problem. However,

You can use `git pull origin branch2` while you are on `master`. This will pull all the updates on `branch2` to `master`.

Here `origin` is your remote. In case of confusion, consider using `gitk`, which is a very handy tool to visually represent the git repository.

Comment: "* branch branch2 -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date"
After git pull origin branch2, when I am on origin branch

Comment: use `git branch` to check the exact branch or use `gitk` on the git repo to see exactly what is on your branch. If your `branch2` branch is ahead of your `master` branch it should pull the updates, unless you already done so.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the one added file you can:

```
git checkout master
git checkout branch2 -- the_file
git add the_file
git commit -m "adding the_file from branch2"
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if on branch2 I also pushed:
"git push origin branch2".
How can, after it, I send the_file to master branch?

Comment: Same way, you checkout the file from branch2, commit on master and push to origin/master

Comment: A ok :) I thought, that there is any one command. Ok, thank You for help.